# Check if node is (in)directly connected to a specific node

Tags: c#, search, nodes, root, path-finding

I would like to be able to check if a particular node is connected to a root node either directly or indirectly. The code below works to some extent, but quite often fails to find the root (when its obvious it should).

EDIT: The usage of the word root in this post does not refer to any reserved term and is only a spontaneous name for the boolean variable which marks the node as 'special'.

So far:

```
//The node
public class Node
{
    public Node[] connectedNodes;
    public bool rootNode;
}

//The function
public static bool HasRootNode(Node fromNode)
{
    List<Node> Processed = new List<Node>();
    Stack<Node> WorkStack = new Stack<Node>(FromNode.connectedNodes);

    Processed.Add(fromNode);

    while (WorkStack.Count != 0)
    {
        Node workItem = WorkStack.Pop();

        foreach (Node cNode in workItem.connectedNodes)
        {
            if (Processed.Contains(cNode))
                continue;

            if (cNode.rootNode)
                return true; // Found..

            WorkStack.Push(cNode); // Queue all of the connectedNodes for this node
            Processed.Add(cNode); // This node has been processed..
        }
    }

    return false; // Not found..
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does your graph contain loops, or is it strictly directed?

Comment: Is there a reason why your `Node` is a `struct` and not a `class`? The presence of an array property already implies a level of indirection (the struct *references* an array) and suggests to me that your choice might be misguided.

Comment: Not sure if it contains any loops, having a hard time trying to visualize flow. It actually is a class but I changed it to a struct for some odd reason when trimming the code down to only relevant things, nice catch!

Comment: Can you define "root node"? It seems to me that, because your nodes only refer to children and not parents, the root (as I understand the term) in a directed graph will never be accessible from its connectedNodes.

Comment: In your code you write `if (cNode.RootConnection)`, yet your class definition for `Node` has no such property. Also, your input variable is `fromNode`, yet your code refers to some other variable named `FromNode`. Also, the fields in your `Node` class are `private` by default, and therefore not accessible. You might consider making them public properties instead. It would be nice if you posted compilable code.

Comment: Also, the name `FindRootNote` implies that the root node will be returned. You might consider renaming it to `HasRootNode` (either that, or return the root node when it's found).

Comment: Oh dear, You guys have eagle vision! Thanks for spotting my formatting errors. It should all be correct now I hope.

Comment: The idea is that you insert a node as an argument and it will search as far as it is connected and see if it finds ANY node which has rootNode set to true.

Comment: @spender I do appologize for my choice of variable names but it does make more sense to where I apply it although 'rooted' is probably more descriptive. In my app I use it to single out the nodes that are not connected to any rooted node which are then discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, only checked the sub-nodes of workItem but not the workItem node itself. :)

Thank you for your time and attention!

```
//The node
public class Node
{
    public Node[] connectedNodes;
    public bool rootNode;
}

//The function
public static bool HasRootNode(Node fromNode)
{
    List<Node> Processed = new List<Node>();
    Stack<Node> WorkStack = new Stack<Node>(FromNode.connectedNodes);

    Processed.Add(fromNode);

    while (WorkStack.Count != 0)
    {
        Node workItem = WorkStack.Pop();
        if (workItem.rootNode)
            return true; // Found..

        foreach (Node cNode in workItem.connectedNodes)
        {
            if (Processed.Contains(cNode))
                continue;

            if (cNode.rootNode)
                return true; // Found..

            WorkStack.Push(cNode); // Queue all of the connectedNodes for this node
            Processed.Add(cNode); // This node has been processed..
        }
    }

    return false; // Not found..
}
```